# How do I convert a SAV. file to a CSV file in R?

Tags: r, csv, spss

I am trying to convert SAV. to CSV. with R. However, I got an error. My data was imported as a SAV. file, but I wonder whether the problem may be that the data is in tbl_df data.frame. Could this be a problem? What is the error and the correct coding to continue with analyses? Below codes and output. Thank you!

```
library(haven)

HNIR62FL_data_2 <- read_sav("~/DHS/HNIR62SV/HNIR62FL_data_2.SAV")

View(HNIR62FL_data_2)

install.packages("foreign")

library("foreign")

class(HNIR62FL_data_2)

[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

write.table(read.spss("HNIR62FL_data_2.sav"), file = "from_sav_data.csv", quote = FALSE, sep = ",") 

Error in read.spss("HNIR62FL_data_2") : unable to open file: 'No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error seems to be related to the missing extension in "HNIR62FL_data_2" inside `write.table(...)`. You just need to provide it.

Also, you don't need to keep `install.packages()` in your script. This should be enough:

```r
library(haven)

HNIR62FL_data_2 <- read_sav("~/DHS/HNIR62SV/HNIR62FL_data_2.SAV")

write.table(HNIR62FL_data_2, file = "from_sav_data.csv", quote = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

Comment: I think you have the file in a different directory since it seemed to work fine when you called `read_sav()`. Try with that same directory: "~/DHS/HNIR62SV/HNIR62FL_data_2.SAV".

Comment: Also, if the first `read_sav()` works fine, you don't really need to read the file again inside `write.table()`. Just use the object you created after `read_sav()`, as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your support, @Samuel Calderon. I was able to convert the file.

Comment: Sure, don't forget to mark the question as answered